# How to get model/serial of USB hard drive without opening up case (on Windows)?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I recently bought a new 2,5 USB3 HDD (Western Digital Elements) and I'm curious what drive is actually inside (mainly because I'd like to know if it's using CMR or SMR, or is there any other way to get that?).
From various other pages I found running `wmic diskdrive get Name, Manufacturer, Model, InterfaceType, MediaType, SerialNumber` in command prompt, this works for the internal drives, but for this one I get `WXB2A92F2SFH` which I think is the serial of the controller or something, but not of the actual drive (at least googling for it brings up nothing).

Comment: Hmm. Works for my Seagate drives. I don't have a WD drive.

Comment: Any SMART tool should be able to get it as long as USB bridge passes on commands. I made tiny tool that tries SCSI passthrough to USB drives, https://www.disktuna.com/free-drive-passport-utility/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SMART tool should tell the actual drive, here's one of my external Toshiba's:

[image]

I also made a free, small, simple and unpolished utility that should reveal the actual drive as long as USB enclosure passes on SCSI commands, https://www.disktuna.com/free-drive-passport-utility/

One of my other external Toshiba's:

[image]